# How can I say that I'm doing something without a valid reason?

Tags: word-request

How to say that I'm not doing something out of a valid reason?

For example:

> When I elected a course because my friends did. **OR** 
>   When I invested in a stock because its symbol sounded like my name.

How should I describe such situation where I make a decision that's not based on solid reasoning, but rather some trivial information?

Comment: Perhaps you used your intuition?

Comment: To me, these are not intuitive choices because they are based on trivial information or whimsy. Intuition is knowing something to be true without knowing how one knows it. Intuition of a subject field (such as street smarts, people, business, animals, mathematical proofs) can be created through experience. ("I can tell he's lying." | "How?" | "I don't know, but I can tell.")  Others may attribute intuition to unknown capabilities of mind, but I don't think the above examples would neatly fit into most people's idea of intuition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of good answers so far, but somehow nobody's mentioned the great terms **whim**, **whimsy** and **whimsical** which seem to me to closest fit your examples.  Picking a stock because its symbol sounded like one's name is a great example of whimsy, a totally whimsical thing to do, something one did **on a whim**.

Unlike all the terms mentioned so far, there's no negative connotation to whimsy and whimsical.  Whim can have a negative connotation, but doesn't necessarily.

The aforementioned **capricious** is also good, but perhaps more pertinent is **caprice**, "a sudden and unaccountable change of mood or behavior" which has less negative connotation than **capricious** (which can go either way).  If the mood aspect is applicable, you may also want to check out **mecurial** which, before it became an SCC meant in thrall to one's mood of the moment.

Addendum: Also in a similar vein: the idioms **on a lark**, **for a lark**, **for kicks**, and **for kicks and giggles**.

Comment: A common, though somewhat vulgar, variation of your last suggestion would be "for *shits* and giggles"

Answer (score 7):

I am going to write an answer here, *just for the heck of it*.

Comment: +1 for showing, telling, and being funny all at the same time.

Comment: Note that this is quite informal.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Good point. I consider this an informal forum, however you would not say this to your parents, boss, or in any formal situation.

Comment: *Just for fun,* I'm going to make a comment here.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some definitional one-liners, psychology, and prose-style description:

- My decision to X was arbitrary.
- My decision to X was irrational.
- My decision to X was impulsive.
- In psychology, it can depend on the reason for making the decision.  If it just "seemed like a good idea" that might be referred to as [**impulsive decisions**](https://www.google.com/search?q=impulsive+decision+making).  If one makes decisions based on irrational connections and connotations, that could be a sign of schizophrenia.
- Prose: I wanted to go to University X, but my friend suggested I go to University Y so we could be roommates, so that's what I did. In hindsight, I did not have any judgement. I floated wherever the wind would blow. I was very suggestible, and I've made many decisions impulsively and capriciously.

Comment: I would add that hereabouts, the precise expression "it seemed like a good idea at the time" has come to be an self-deprecating idiom meaning, basically, "I had no real justification whatsoever."

Comment: @Codeswitcher, Thanks! I just want to clarify what you're saying here.  Good point on it being idiomatic. Like "Why did you do [some very stupid thing]" / "I dunno.. seemed like a good idea at the time." In this case, it means one made a bad judgement.  The reason they did the thing was actually because perhaps it did seem like a good idea, or perhaps they didn't even think about it much.

Comment: Exactly.  Might be accompanied by a wry smile, a sheepish look, and/or a shrug.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could convey this. I'm writing what I generally use.

> I joined the course **simply** because my friends did. 
>   I invested in a stock **simply** because its symbol sounded like my name.

I could not find the exact meaning of *simply* in a dictionary the way I used it here but I'm pretty sure that adding *simply* to these sentences in such contexts means "for no solid reason and simply - just like that".

Note that for all your decisions there in the sentences, there might not be *valid reasons* but certainly, *there are reasons (your friends and the symbol respectively!* :)

Comment: @AlexSu (the OP), in the case that you like this answer (which could work too, though I think you're looking for something else), these words can be used as well as *simply (because)*: *just*, *only*, and *merely*.