# What to call someone who always says he is doing something without a/for no reason?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, expressions

Whenever you ask this person for his motivation for doing something or why he thinks something etc. you'll get an immediate response along the lines of "no reason/there is no meaning to it."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I say that I'm doing something without a valid reason?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23738/how-can-i-say-that-im-doing-something-without-a-valid-reason)

Comment: @jimsug - but this asks for a term to call that sort of person. That is different from the act as in the previously asked question?

Comment: *A jerk* --if he **always** says that he's doing something for no reason.

Comment: It could be argued that someone that does something that is _whimsical_ could himself be called _whimsical_. Hmm.

Comment: I think *mindless* might work, [mindless people do not think about what they are doing](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/mindless).

Comment: @jimsug it's not a duplicate of that.

Comment: Everything I can think of other than "free spirit" is an insult or describes a mental problem.  The particular word you use would be your impression of their character or mental ability that explains to you why they are this way.

Comment: @Denise - If those words may be insults, what would they be? Anything that could be an answer, is decent.

Comment: Intellectual capacity insults: Moron, Imbecile, Simpleton, Witless

Comment: Aren't those too unspecified? I.e. could be used on any you dislike...

Comment: Character insults: Jerk (if the thing done for no reason was mean), Thoughtless, Mindless

Comment: There's no specific word for this, as I said before we're just guessing at the traits of the person that cause them to do things without reasons.

Comment: And they shouldn't be used on any you dislike, even if you're being rude.  They should be used to describe someone not intelligent.  Some of these used to have technical definitions in terms of IQ ratings before we decided to call them all "mentally disabled" because the other words were "bad".

Comment: Talking about IQ, I presume this sort of person cannot, bluntly, be claimed for having a "low IQ"/not such a bright person, can he?

Comment: I always find it remarkable when someone says he does something for no reason. Judging from my perspective, I will assume he's a liar or a very private person. However, still hoped there would be a better word for this kind of person...

Comment: I  think you might recognise the characteristics of the person you're thinking of if you found a description in a good [/thesaurus/].  I can't think of a concise name for either the person or the behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you have a generally positive attitude toward the person/characteristic and think he has a good character or whether you have a generally negative attitude toward him or the characteristic and think he's got a poor character. I think you can see from the answers here that people pick one or the other.

Positive:  whimsical, carefree, easy-going, light-hearted, mellow, unassuming

Negative:  unmotivated, listless, careless, unfocused, devil-be-damned

Answer (score 1):

I would say "He is a person of **Arbitrary** nature.

**Definition** "based on random choice or personal whim, rather than any reason or system."

Answer (score 0):

If he was doing something to the benefit of someone else without their knowledge (and without seeking praise from anyone else) you could call it an [altruistic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/altruistic) act.

However given the context you have I'd say they have some [ulterior](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ulterior) motive in which case any number of adjectives such as [guarded](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/guarded), [sneaky](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sneaky) and [subversive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/subversive) spring to mind

Answer (score 0):

Or take a philosophical approach - describing them as an [existential nihilist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihilism) would be a good place to start.

Comment: This probably isn't helpful to a language learner, as they'll need to be able to explain it to people who they say it to, meaning that they need more knowledge than they're asking for.

Comment: No, thanks. It's fine for the OP. He's read about existentialism and nihilism before, so knows what it is.

Comment: Hey! in two years of StackExchange (although this is my first visit to ELL) this is my first -1. I'm not cross, it's a sort of initiation. I feel grown-up now

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't believe there is a word in English for someone who always says he is doing something without a/for no reason.

But it's a very adaptive language. Feel free to make up one of your own. I'll personally use it a the very first opportunity.

I'm trying to think of some equivalent in Yiddish we could use but it escapes me. Someone help here, please?

Answer (score -1):

Chaotic?

Or if we want to take a page out of D&D, I think this would be chaotic neutral. LOL